# Not able to update TableCelView in UITableViewController when Navigating back from a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a navigation view controller which is linked with a `UITableViewController`.
In the table View Controller I have static cells. I have the Right Label format of Table View Cells. I will navigate to a `UIViewController` when clicked on the `UITableViewCell` then when I navigate back to my `UITableViewController`, I would like to update the Detail Label on my `UITableViewCell`.

I am able to pass the value from th`enter code here`e `UIViewController` to the `UITableViewcontroller`. I have verified this using `NSLog`. But I am not able to update the detail label in the cell.

I used `-(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` but this does not help me because, the table view cell will be updated only when I click on another table view cell. I want this update to happen automatically when I navigate back to `UITableViewController`

Please check the following link
http://www.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/navigation_interface.jpeg

i want something like the above image

How can this be done.

Updated for Code

```
@interface designTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation designTableViewController
{
    glimmpseliteAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 8;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIViewController *uiViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"designSolvingForViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.solvingFor;


    }
    if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        UIViewController *uiViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"designTypeIErrorRate"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.typeIError;
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        UIViewController *uiViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"designNumberOfGroups"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.numberOfGroups;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        UIViewController *uiViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"designRelativeGroupSize"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.relativeGroupSize;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 5)
    {
        UIViewController *uiViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"designSmallestGroupSize"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.smallestGroupSize;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 6)
    {
        UIViewController *uiViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"designMeansAndVariance"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.meansAndVariance;
    }
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.solvingFor;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //tb.textLabel.text =@"Sample";
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.typeIError;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //tb.textLabel.text =@"Sample";
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.numberOfGroups;
    }


    if(indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //tb.textLabel.text =@"Sample";
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.relativeGroupSize;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 5)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //tb.textLabel.text =@"Sample";
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.smallestGroupSize;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 6)
    {
        UITableViewCell *tb = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //tb.textLabel.text =@"Sample";
        tb.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.meansAndVariance;
    }
}

@end
```

The first table cell is just a cell which has a button. I have a push UIViewController for that button.

Comment: Please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath, it seem that it is causing the problem..

Answer (score 1):

In viewWillAppear: use [tableView reloadData].

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Then you don't have your cellForRow... method implemented correctly.

Comment: I have added the code for my tableViewController please check

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your model is updated so that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will return the correct cell.

Then use one of the following to update the cell in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)reloadData
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Comment: Yes my cellForRowAtIndexPath: will return the correct cell. But could you be more elaborate how to use the methods you have mentioned as I am new to iOS development

Comment: [self reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<(NSArray *)> withRowAnimation:<(UITableViewRowAnimation)>];

How do I get the IndexPath and UITableViewRowAnimation

Comment: If you don't know the indexPath that you need to reload then just do reloadData.  The indexPath will be the path of whichever cell has new information.  You can save that information on your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` before pushing on your new view, or you can set the TableViewController to not automatically clear the selection, and you can clear it yourself and catch which cell was selected.

Comment: I tried to do viewWillAppear and call the relaoad that did not work

Comment: Call it in `viewDidAppear` maybe.  Otherwise, your `cellForRow...` is not returning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't completely understand UITableView delegate and datasource implementation. A few tips:

---

1. Since you are using storyboard, control drag from your static table cells to the view controller you wish to appear when the cell is selected, this will automatically create a segue (you may be aware of this) so that you don't need to worry about implementing didDeselectRowAtIndexPath, you can connect each static cell to a different VC.
2. You may already have a datasource in your UITableViewController class, such as an array of NSString titles for your detailLabel(s). In tableView:CellForRowAtIndex: you will want to code something like

cell.detailLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

3) In your view controller where these titles are being changed, you want to establish a delegate connection back to the UITableViewController which updates dataArray with new values. Then in UITableViewController class override setDataArray:(NSArray *)array as follows:

> ```
> - (void)setDataArray:(NSArray *)array {
>     _dataArray = array;  
>    [self.tableView reloadData];
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You have to use tableView:CellForRowAtIndex: to update the content of the cell just like you do to initially create the cell. When the app returns to the list (after a setting is updated in another view) tableView:CellForRowAtIndex: will be called automatically.

Correction: tableView:cellForRowAtIndex will not be called automatically. in your viewWillAppear: put

```
[tableView ReloadData];
```

Comment: Try putting it in viewDidAppear:. If that still doesn't work then you don't have tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: implemented correctly. Show us some code.